# Intercept and edit ajax data before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

So I am trying to write a script that will go out and edit the html for all of my tumblr blogs, so i dont have to do it manually.

The problem is that tumblr doesnt really have a form that i can edit, and then submit through JS.. they have a very strange way of compiling the custom html and submitting an ajax request.

So, i was wondering if there was a way to intercept the ajax call before it goes out, edit a field in the data, and then make the submission my self?

I tried something like this:

```
var submitted = false
$("body").ajaxSuccess(function(evt, request, settings){  
  j = $.parseJSON(settings.data)  
  j.custom_theme = "PUT HTML HERE"
  if (!submitted)
    $.post(settings.url, j, function(data){
      console.log(data);
      submitted = true;
    })
})
```

But i got a 403 forbidden error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but must this be done with a custom script? It sounds like this will only be used by you, so an extension should work. If so, there is a very useful Firefox extension, in the spirit of Firebug, called [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/). This should be able to do what you want.

It allows you to monitor each request made by the browser, and you can turn on an option that allows you to look at, and edit, every single request before it gets sent.

Comment: I have multiple tumblr blogs. and i am trying to edit the html for all of them... so i dont have to do it manually. it doesnt look like i can automatically use tamper data to work with a script. (i couldnt really get it to work at all) but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty obvious that ajaxSuccess isn't going to work in the way you want it to.
Assign the function which sends the AJAX request a new name and overwrite it. Call the previous function at the end of the new function, i.e. after manipulating the data the way you want.

Comment: Sorry i didnt think i would have to explain my attempt, what the attempt did, was after the initial ajax request was sent successfully it re-submitted it with the changed data. this would and should work.. but it looks like tumblr has done something to tamper with it.

Comment: also, tumblr's script was obscured so it is impossible to read.

Comment: Then, use a javascript deobfuscator / beautifier. Just google and you will most probably find one.